# Why do these two methods not work correctly in a single print statement?

Tags: java, methods

I am using two built in methods, **charAt()** and **getNumericValue()** to get the character of a string and its numerical value, when I try to use both methods in the same println() it gives me an incorrect result but when I put them in separate print methods they work fine. Although my example works I am curious as to why this is?

**This gives the correct result**

```
            {
                // dataStream is a String taken from the user. e.g. "Ninja"
                // Take in dataStream, calculate the value of each character.
                for ( int i = 0; i < dataStream.length() ; i++ )

                    {
                        System.out.print ( dataStream.charAt(i) ) ; // Print the Character at i,
                        System.out.print( Character.getNumericValue ( dataStream.charAt(i) ) ) ;    // Print the value of the character at i.
                        System.out.println ( " ") ; // Tidy
                    }


            }
```

**This doesn't**

```
            {

                // dataStream is a String taken from the user. e.g. "Ninja"
                // Take in dataStream, calculate the value of each character.
                for ( int i = 0; i < dataStream.length() ; i++ )

                    {

                       System.out.print ( dataStream.charAt(i) + Character.getNumericValue ( dataStream.charAt(i) )  ) ;
                       System.out.println ( " ") ; // Tidy

                    }


            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `+` only works as concatenations when one of the elements is a `String`, and what you have is a `char` and an `int` value.

So, it promotes (converts) the `char` to `int`, adds both numbers and that is what it prints.

You may:

- Convert to String both the char (`Character.toString(char)`) and the int (`Integer.toString(int)`), or one of them.
- Add a String in the middle `dataStream.charAt(i) + "" + Character.getNumericValue(dataStream.charAt(i))`. It would be decomposed as `(dataStream.charAt(i) + "") + Character.getNumericValue(dataStream.charAt(i))`. The first part will evaluate as String concatenation (because of "") and the rest will be also String concatenation (because the result of the first part will be a String). As a side benefit, use an empty space or a symbol to separate both values.

Answer (score 2):

> when I try to use both methods in the same println() it gives me an incorrect result but when I put them in separate print methods they work fine.

It is because in your second approach, you are printing the sum of the ascii value and int value of "ninja" letter by letter due to the `+` operator within `println()`.

You may overcome that by appending a string literal before the character:

```
System.out.print ("" + dataStream.charAt(i) + Character.getNumericValue ( dataStream.charAt(i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `+` operators behaves differently depending on the given types. This should give you some idea what is going on:

```
System.out.println(charType + charType);    //Addition occurs
System.out.println(intType + charType);     //Addition occurs
System.out.println(StringType + charType);  //Concatenation occurs
System.out.println(charType + StringType);  //Concatenation occurs
System.out.println(StringType + intType);   //Concatenation occurs
System.out.println(intType + StringType);   //Concatenation occurs

System.out.println('A' + 'A');       //prints 130 (65+65)
System.out.println(5 + 'A');         //prints 70 (65+5)
System.out.println("" + 'B');        //prints "B"
System.out.println('B' + "");        //prints "B"
System.out.println("" + 7);          //prints "7"
System.out.println(7 + "");          //prints "7"
System.out.println("" + 'A' + 'B');  //prints "AB"
```

Answer (score 0):

the *return type* of  `Character.getNumericValue() method` is *int type* and `charAt()` return *char type*.

---

then the value of `char type` add `int type` return a value of`int type`